# PHP Read File Line By Line and output to 1 line

Tags: php

I am trying to get a file that looks like this:

> Name1
>
> Name2
>
> Name3

and want it to output like so:

Name1, Name2, Name3

I tried this but am getting nowhere with it:

```
    $list = file_get_contents("tready.txt");
$convert = explode("\n", $list);
for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)  
{
    $list = $convert[$i].', '; //write value by index
}
$this->say('Currently waiting: ' . $list);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
$list = file("tready.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
echo implode(", ", $list);
```

Docs: [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Easier:

```
$list = implode(', ', file('tready.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll achieve that simply with that code:

```
$list = file_get_contents("tready.txt");
$convert = implode(', ', explode("\n", $list));
```

What's happening here: you merge elements of an array (exploded `$list`) with `,` string.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier:
`echo str_replace("\n", ', ', file_get_contents("tready.txt"));`